# Consuming to a .NET SOAP service from PHP with authentication

Tags: php, .net, soap, soap-client

I've been hunting for several days for a solution to this but had no luck.

I got my starter code from http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/04/16/soap-client-calling-net-web-service/ .

Here's the code as adjusted (with a fake key):

```
<?php
// create a connection to the local host mono .NET pull back the wsdl to get the functions names
// and also the parameters and return values
$client = new SoapClient("https://realServer/events.asmx?WSDL",
array(
  "trace"      => 1,        // enable trace to view what is happening
  "exceptions" => 0,        // disable exceptions
  "cache_wsdl" => 0)        // disable any caching on the wsdl, encase you alter the wsdl server
);

// get a response from the WSDL zend server function getQuote for the day monday
print_r( $client->GetSingleEvent(array("APIKey" => "HISY20Y4-8405-91SK-L0S7-9A17252E548A", "EventId" => "2559")));

// display what was sent to the server (the request)
echo "<p>Request :".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."</p>";
// display the response from the server
echo "<p>Response:".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."</p>";
?>
```

Here's what the actual xml request should look like (as tested in Soap UI)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:cer="http://cermsystem.net/">
<soapenv:Header>
  <tem:Credentials>
     <!--Optional:-->

  <tem:APIKey>HISY20Y4-8405-91SK-L0S7-9A17252E548A</tem:APIKey></tem:Credentials>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tem:GetSingleEvent>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <cer:GetEventByIDRQ>
        <!--Optional:-->

     <cer:EventId>2559</cer:EventId></cer:GetEventByIDRQ>
  </tem:GetSingleEvent>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the current output I am getting from the script after sending to .NET SOAP server:

```
SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
[string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /Library/WebServer/Documents/soap6.php [line:protected] => 15 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /Library/WebServer/Documents/soap6.php [line] => 15 [function] => __call [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => GetSingleEvent [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [APIKey] => 8F0A395B-8405-480B-871C-9A17252E548A ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /Library/WebServer/Documents/soap6.php [line] => 15 [function] => GetSingleEvent [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [APIKey] => 8F0A395B-8405-480B-871C-9A17252E548A ) ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [faultcode] => soap:Server [detail] => )

Request :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:GetSingleEvent/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</faultstring>
<detail />
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I think the problem is that the .NET server isn't receiving the right inputs for APIKey and EventId, but I've been unable to get that part to work. Does the APIKey need to be sent as part of the header? If so how would I do that in combination with reading the WSDL

Comment: Does sending the request manually work?  The faultstring you're getting there looks like it is the standard failure message for .NET web services. We would need to see more about the web service (particularly the backtrace it is returning) to be able to figure out what error it is throwing and why. There's nothing obviously wrong with the PHP SOAP code as you've shown it.

Comment: @Gian Not sure exactly what you mean by manually. Sending the request as XML direct from another app (Soap UI) works fine and generates the correct response. I can send you the proper url and key via facebook if you want to see the actual process in action?

Comment: Are these really the same request?  One is invoking 'GetSingleEvent' and the other is invoking 'GetEventList'. Your suspicion that the credentials not being sent is the problem would appear to be the right one.

Comment: @gian well spotted. Changed the request I was using half way through writing the post as GetEventList only had a single parameter, the APIKey, which made it too simple for testing. (Have now updated post) Any idea how to get the APIKey into the request header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model correct XML, you have 'APIKey' and such nested inside a 'Credentials' element, inside the SOAP header.  Your PHP code won't generate this.

You need something like [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) that permits you to add headers to your soap request.  The header you want to add is something like this:

```
$ns = 'http://tempuri.org/'; //Namespace of the webservice
$headerbody = array("APIKey" => "HISY20Y4-8405-91SK-L0S7-9A17252E548A");

//Create Soap Header.        
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'Credentials', $headerbody);        

//set the Headers of Soap Client. 
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

At that point, your request should work (although that code is untested).

Comment: Thanks @Gian, that sent me in the right direction. (once I worked out the last line had to go after new SoapClient). I'll post the final code below, as I had to wrestle with nested XML as well and i haven't been able to find a good solution to this anywhere.