# soap call to .net from php paramaters not passing

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap

I am trying to get php to just simply pass a parameter to a .net web service however it never adds the parameter to the call, but it does call the function.

Here is the php:

```
$client = new SoapClient("example.com/page.asmx?WSDL");
$header = new SoapHeader('example.com/', 'UserCredentials', 
    array(
        'userName' => "cory", 
        'password' => "test", 
    )
);
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));

print_r($client->add("test1234"));
```

here is the .net

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader( "consumer", Required = true )]
public string add( string id )
{
    if( id == null || id != "test1234" ) {
       return "ID Invalid: " + consumer.ToString() + ":::" + id;
    }
    return "good";
}

public class UserCredentials : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
{
    public string userName;
    public string password;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return userName + ":" + password;
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this it will print

```
stdClass Object ( [addResult] => ID Invalid: cory:test::: )
```

So the credentials are passing in properly but the value never makes it. Any Help?

Comment: Your parameter is named `id` & in the method you use it as `appid`. It's a typo in the question, or in the application?

Answer (score 0):

.NET simply does not do SOAP correctly. I don't have access to the code anymore, but I believe you need to do something ridiculous like wrap your properties in another associative array under a key named 'parameters'.

[Here's my answered question that got my application working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263557/how-is-php-5-3-soap-request-formed)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use an associative array for your parameters :

```
array("id" => "test1234")
```

So your soap call :

```
print_r($client->add(array("id" => "test1234"));
```

Documentation PHP.NET : http://php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.soapcall.php#110390